# New version of chrome extension is not getting updated on user's computers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My team has built a chrome extension that is published in the chrome store. We've updated the version in the manifest.json file and published multiple new versions, but our users are not getting updated to the newest version unless they completely close and restart their chrome browser.

I've read posts about adding this code to the service-worker.js but it has no effect

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener((details) => {
  chrome.runtime.reload();
});
```

We have waited as long as a week, but autoupdates never occur.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.